# react-bootstrap: Tab's tabClassName attribute overriden by default

Tags: css, tabs, react-bootstrap

I am using react-bootstrap, specifically  Tabs and Tab. Tab has a built-in attribute [tabClassName](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components.html#tabs-props-pane) that takes a string. The instructions for usage are "tabClassName is used as className for the associated NavItem".

So I set `<Tab tabClassName="main-tab">`.

My goal is to remove the blue outline that appears when the tab is focused on. However, the following CSS does nothing.

```
.main-tab, .main-tab:active, .main-tab:focus {
    outline: none !important;
}
```

Here is the site inspection:
[image]

How do I get rid of the blue focus outline?

Comment: This is a bad idea, and goes against best practices. For accessibility purposes, you should try to avoid messing with the browser's default focus outline/styling. http://www.outlinenone.com/

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. What do you think of the solution below?

Comment: I would advise against it—there's a reason why a framework like Bootstrap leaves the focus styling in. It removes the outline, but the outline is important for someone who is using a keyboard (because they can't use a mouse) to figure out where they are navigating on the page. If you do not like the browser default styling, you need to define your own.

Comment: Noted. Thanks for pointing that out to me, I wasn't aware of that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution:

the following CSS works:

```
.main-tab > a,
.main-tab > a:focus {
    outline: none;
}
```